# Where can I find a list of supported Application Manifest scopes for Google Apps Marketplace applications?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

The "official" [list of supported scopes](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/manifest#supported_scopes) appears incomplete.

Specifically, I need to move from the (deprecated) Google Apps Provisioning API to the Admin SDK, and I am not sure what the correct scopes are.

These are a few endpoints I am interested in.

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/general/currentNumberOfUsers
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members
```

For these endpoints, I am only interested in read-only access.  Does the Admin SDK support read-only scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing:

Scopes for devices

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos   For all Chrome device operations, use this global scope
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos.readonly  Use to limit the administrator's scope for only retrieving Chrome devices
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.mobile     For all mobile device operations, use this global scope
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.mobile.readonly    Use to limit the administrator's scope for only retrieving mobile device
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.mobile.action  Use to limit the administrator's scope for tasks that take an action on a mobile device.

Scopes for groups, group aliases, and group members

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group For all group operations, use this global group, group alias, and member scope.
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly    Use to limit the administrator's scope for retrieving group, group alias, and member information.

Scopes for organization units

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit   For all organization unit operations use this global organization unit scope
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly  Use to limit an administrator's scope for retrieving organization units

Scopes for users and user aliases

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user  For all user and user alias operations, use this global user scope
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly Use to limit the administrator's scope for retrieving users or user aliases

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  How did I miss that page? :-/  Do you know if there is a readonly scope for the settings API? https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/auth

Comment: @GICodeWarrior I don't work with the `admin-sdk` api actually, just happened to chance upon the information while looking up another api and was wondering why everyone else has given the question a pass..